# Automation of Oracle XE installation with ansible and vagrant - Oracle environment variables not correctly visible?

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, ansible

I am currently trying to automate Oracle Database XE using ansible playbook. Everything with the installation seems to be fine, except for the step in which environment variables for Oracle are set:

```
source /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh
```

The code in ansible playbook looks like this:

```
- name: setup oracle environment
  shell: source /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh
  shell: reset
  shell: /bin/echo 'source /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh' >> /home/vagrant/.bash_profile
- name: create users and schemas on the oracle database
  shell: sqlplus SYSTEM/root@XE @ create_schemas_users.sql
```

Then, when I run the ansible playbook, at the end of the process, I get something like this:

```
TASK [create users and schemas on the oracle database] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

fatal: [wemdbc01]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sqlplus SYSTEM/root@XE @ create_schemas_users.sql", "delta": "0:00:00.002841", "end": "2017-05-30 08:40:50.652786", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-05-30 08:40:50.649945", "stderr": "/bin/sh: sqlplus: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: sqlplus: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/var/wminst/ansible-config/playbooks/oracle-xe.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

wemdbc01                   : ok=6    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1

Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

What am I doing wrong? Why after running `source /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh` and resetting the terminal `sqlplus` is not visible for bash?

Answer (score 0):

The remote shell cannot find the sqlplus program. Find the path of the program on the remote system and try appending it to the PATH variable as the first part of the ansible shell  command;

```
shell: "export PATH=$PATH:/mypath/sqlplus; source /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh"
```

Comment: you didn't *append* to the path, you replaced the path ... maybe `PATH=$PATH:/mypath/sqlplus` ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah, thanks - yes, that was an omission. Fixed now